# Identifying Sockets and problems with Dictionary

Tags: c#, sockets

So what I am trying to do is to somehow identify sockets. I want to put the sockets in a list with the IP Addresses.

I tried using Dictionary which seemed to be what I needed.

```
Dictionary<string, Socket> SocketId = new Dictionary<string, Socket>();
```

But then issues with using the Dictionary started. I put

```
Console.WriteLine("Count: " + SocketId.Count);
```

in a timer, and the output was different every time.

[image]

To be more exact, when a client connects, the socket with its IP is added to the dictionary. There is no remove command so there is no way the code is removing the dictionaries entry.

The second dictionaries problem was that when I tried to use

```
form.SocketId.ContainsKey(ip);
```

It always showed it doesn't contain the value even when made sure it was added.

When i have the clients ip, i want to use it to get the socket assigned to it.

So is there any worthwhile way to fix the dictionary problem, if not, is there any other way i could store the socket and ip?

Comment: A Listener can accept many clients so you need to collect sockets in the Asynchronous Accept method.  Then remove sockets when they close.

Comment: That's in progress, but I don't see how is that related to the question.

Comment: Asynchronous programming is weird, dawg. Dictionary is not thread safe. Use a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead!

Comment: Tried using `ConcurrentDictionary`, has the same issues like `Dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ConcurrentDictionary` or implement it yourself using a `lock`.

```
public class SocketDick {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, Socket> sockets = new Dictionary<string, Socket>();

        private readonly object @lock = new object();

        public bool TryAdd(string key,Socket socket) {
            bool added;
            lock (@lock) {
                added=this.sockets.TryAdd(key, socket);
            }
            return added;
        }
        public bool TryRemove(string key) {
            bool remove = false ;
            if(this.sockets.Any(x=>x.Key==key)) {
                lock (@lock) {
                    remove = this.sockets.Remove(key);
                }
            }
            return remove;
        }
    }
```